# Load images from file (any pc works) C++ Builder

Tags: c++, c++builder, c++builder-6

I want to load some images from a folder but I want to works on another pc.

I load an image like this:

```
Image1->Picture->Bitmap->LoadFromFile("C:\\Users\\Raul\\Desktop\\Cards BMP\\2_of_diamonds.bmp" );
```

And when I run project on another pc that "C:\Users\Raul\Desktop\" is diffrent.

How can I load that image from another pc?

I use C++ Builder 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a folder called Images where your project is, where are the files are created etc. Then you just have to do

```
Image1->Picture->Bitmap->LoadFromFile("Images/2_of_diamonds.bmp" );
```

And it can be done from any pc because the image is in the project folder.

Comment: Thank you that helps me alot  .

Comment: Opening a file using a relative path will attempt to open it relative to the calling process's **current working directory**, which can (and usually does) change value dynamically during the process's lifetime. If you want to load a file whose location is relative to the executable's installation folder, you should first retrieve the absolute path of the executable's folder and then append any relative paths to it as needed, eg: `String ImagesPath = ExtractFilePath(Application->ExeName) + "Images\\"; ... Image1->Picture->Bitmap->LoadFromFile(ImagesPath + "2_of_diamonds.bmp");`

Answer (score 1):

If you need to load a JPEG (*.jpg), you can use:

```
Image1->Picture->LoadFromFile("Images/2_of_diamonds.jpg" );
```